remove JSESSIONIDVERSION in set-cookie
In my project, I want to rename the JSESSIONIDVERSION cookie. I have already renamed the JSESSIONID to another name, but I am unsure how to rename JSESSIONIDVERSION.
We are using JAX-RS, NGINX, Payara Micro, and Hibernate for session handling.
I tried using ContainerResponseFilter, but the header did not appear in the HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ContainerRequestContext, or ContainerResponseContext.
However, I am able to see the JSESSIONIDVERSION cookie in the browser.

It's not possible to configure a different name for the JSESSIONIDVERSION cookie, its name is hardcoded. If you need to change it, you would need to change the code of Payara Micro and rebuild it.
You can raise a request to make the name of JSESSIONIDVERSION configurable on Payara issue tracker. You can have a look also whether the GlassFish team can implement this option in GlassFish and then you might like using runnable GlassFish Embedded instead of Payara Micro.
